# Glide loading some images but not all

Tags: android, android-glide, android-popupwindow, android-photoview

I am facing a weird thing using Glide library( v4.2.0 with compile SDK 26) along with christbanes [Photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library. I'm able to load, display some images( size <300 Kb ) and able to perform zooming gestures with the Photoview library but not on all the images. Although the images are present at the location /storage/emulated/0/hhp_images/ but still Glide loads some images and shows this error for others.

```
W/Glide: Load failed for file:///storage/emulated/0/hhp_images/cylhd_chang.jpg with size [1080x1704]
         class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
           Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
             Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/hhp_images/cylhd_chang.jpg (No such file or directory)
           Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
             Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 2)
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/hhp_images/cylhd_chang.jpg (No such file or directory)
             at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
             at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:700)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResourceFromUri(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:87)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:62)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.StreamLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(StreamLocalUriFetcher.java:17)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:41)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:293)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:263)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:386)
I/Glide: Root cause (2 of 2)
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
             at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:283)
             at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:977)
             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:905)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(FileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:14)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:41)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:293)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:388)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:118)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:46)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:61)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:293)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:263)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
             at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:386)
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

The size of images it is unable to load is variable i.e. in sme cases it is 150 Kb or in some 300 Kb. So I think this is not due to large size. But I'm unable to figure out the problem.

This is the code for the class which is calling glide and loading images in a PopupWindow -

```
public class PhotoFullPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {

    View view;
    Context mContext;
    PhotoView photoView;
    ProgressBar loading;
    ViewGroup parent;
    private static PhotoFullPopupWindow instance = null;


    public PhotoFullPopupWindow(Context ctx, int layout, View v, String imageUrl, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(((LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate( R.layout.popup_photo_full, null)
                , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setElevation(5.0f);
        }

//        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        this.mContext = ctx;
        this.view = getContentView();
        ImageButton closeButton = (ImageButton) this.view.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
        setOutsideTouchable(true);

        setFocusable(true);
        // Set a click listener for the popup window close button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Dismiss the popup window
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        //---------Begin customising this popup--------------------

        photoView = (PhotoView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
//        loading = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        photoView.setMaximumScale(6);
        parent = (ViewGroup) photoView.getParent();
        // ImageUtils.setZoomable(imageView);
        //----------------------------
        if (bitmap != null) {
//            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                parent.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), Constants.fastblur(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true))));// ));
            } else {
                onPalette(Palette.from(bitmap).generate());

            }
            photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
//            loading.setIndeterminate(true);
//            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            GlideApp.with(ctx) .asBitmap()
                    .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUrl)))
//                    .override(600, 200)
                    .error(R.drawable.sample_image)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
//                            loading.setIndeterminate(false);
//                            loading.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error: Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            dismiss();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
//                                parent.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), Constants.fastblur(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, 50, 50, true))));// ));
                                parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            } else {
                                onPalette(Palette.from(resource).generate());

                            }
                            photoView.setImageBitmap(resource);

//                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })



                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(photoView);

            showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
        //------------------------------

    }

    public void onPalette(Palette palette) {
        if (null != palette) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) photoView.getParent().getParent();
            parent.setBackgroundColor(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(Color.GRAY));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried loading the image in a normal ImageView 200dp * 200dp instead of Photoview but still got the same error.

**SOLVED** - Actually the code had no problem in it. Problem was there with device - Moto G4 Plus. When i ran the app on other emulators it ran sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the app Android version is 6.0, you must require Runtime permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` .

You can do like this

```
 /**
 * permission code
 */
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

/**
 * requestPermissions and do something
 *
 */
public void requestRead() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        readFile();
    }
}

/**
 * do you want to do
 */
public void readFile() {
    // do something
}

/**
 * onRequestPermissionsResult
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            readFile();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(ToolbarActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**or**

You can try https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

Comment: In my recycler view of images, some images are getting displayed onclick but some are not. So i think if some images are getting displayed then permission to read external storage must be present otherwise they would also fail to load. Isn't it?  I added this code but still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got URLs without `https://` (for instance, www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png).

I saw that from log:

> I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 3)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /example.com/static/img/brands/hyundai.png (No such file or directory)